# How to find LP Tokens contract code to import

Tags: solidity, erc-20, staking

I add liquidity to Uniswap v2 (rinkeby) with myToken and ETH and got some LP Tokens (UNI-V2 ERC2-0).

And I'm going to connect to LP Token's function transferFrom(). How I'm understanding I have to make variable like "Type public lpToken" where "Type" is a contract name of LP Token.

So the question is how I can import code of the LP Token's contract or I can use OpenZeppeline like a standart ERC20?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import "./MyToken.sol";

contract Staking {
    MyToken public myToken;

    constructor(MyToken _myToken) public {
        myToken = _myToken;
    }

    function stake(uint256 _value) public {
        myToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _value);
    }
}

//0x186B0A571252f523316379729369900d638cc22b (MTN)
//0x709547aE2aCE54718f87a9b1d974CaEEE97Ef8A1 UNI-V2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just used ERC20 contract like

```
import "./MyToken.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Staking {
    MyToken private myToken;
    **ERC20 private lpToken;**
```